# How do I use a project source package written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, build, makefile

I have just read the Ruby User's Guide at http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/getstarted.html, I didn't find what I was looking for... which is, How do I use ruby source which I downloaded? There's a Makefile in it, do I just run GNU make -f like for any other source?

All I am trying to do is build and use whatweb (https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/wiki/Installation) from its source package.

Answer (score 1):

Please do read READMEs developers provide. The README will point to https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/wiki/Installation which describe the installation process.

There you find that you need to install dependencies. As already stated Ruby is interpreted and does not need to be compiled.

Comment: yes, I certainly saw that page. It helped me install the dependencies. It did not help me know how to make whatweb work, after extracting it from the tarball. I presume somebody has to know something about how to use Ruby packages, information which is missing from the whatweb install page.

Answer (score 0):

....If I understad it well, you shouldn't build it(Ruby is an interpreted language). You just run the script like:

$ ./whatweb slashdot.org reddit.com
at "2. Example Usage" from whatweb documentation..

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, I only get "command not found". Yes, it's executable.

So, why do you suppose there's a Makefile in there?